# Finding t vlaue in Bezier curve

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, computer-science, curves-and-surfaces, interpolation

According to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122257/finding-the-formula-for-bezier-curve-ratios-hull-point-point-baseline) question, I'm looking for some method to find the t value in Quadratic bezier curve equation:

$$
   B(t)=P_0+t(1-t)P_1+t^2P_2 \space \space  where \space  0 ≤ t ≤ 1
$$

In this equation we have 3 points that that will return $B$ like this picture:

[image]

*This picture downloaded from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)*

As you can see, The changes on $t$ will change the $B$ position. Now my question is I have position of these points $P_0 ,P_1,P_2, B$ , is there any way to find $t$ with these parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You can just solve the equation you display directly.
For example, let
$$
P_0=(0,0),\;\; P_2=(1,0),\;\; P_1=(0.4,0.8) \;,
$$
and suppose $B=(0.174,0.168)$:

---

[image: BPlot]

---

Then your equation
$$
B=P_0+t(1-t)P_1+t^2P_2 
$$
becomes after substitution,
$$
\left(0.174,0.168\right)=\left( t^2+0.4(1-t) t, \; 0.8 (1-t) t \right) \;,
$$
and its solution is $t=0.3$.

Maybe what's confusing you is this is two equations in one unknown.
But both are quadratic equations. So solving for the $x$-component
yields $t=\{-0.97,0.3\}$ and solving for the $y$-component yields $t=\{0.3,0.7\}$.
So clearly only $t=0.3$ matches both components of $B$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there any way to convert this method to programming function? cause I should use this method in a program, it seems hard to use this method in program.

Comment: @Gabriel: Just implement solving the two quadratic equations, and select the common root